# .height returns value over 10x the actual one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Got a dynamic bubble showing up inside a listing. I'm trying to set it above a button by jquery calculating its height, adding a few more pixels, and setting negative "top" style. But with div's height at 34px, it returns height of 400 something.

Tried both: .height and .outerHeight

Jquery

```
if($(".bubble")[0]) {       
        $(".bubble").each(function(){
            const self = this;
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(self).removeClass("hide");
                if ($(window).width()> 1000) {
                    var bubblehe = ($(this).height()+14)*-1;

                } else {
                    var bubblehe = $(this).height+14;
                }
                $(self).css('top',bubblehe);
            }, <?php echo $myoptions['bubble_delay']; ?>)
        });

        $(document.body).click(function(){
            $(".bubble").addClass("hide");
        });
    }
```

css of the .bubble

```
.bubble {
    padding:2px 0;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px #cccaca;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    pointer-events: none;
    color:#e98007;
    font-size:12px;
    transition:0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: inside your setTimeout callback, use your `self` var, not `this` when retrieving the height